# Nodejs and Orientdb database connection?

Tags: node.js, database-connection, orientdb

I am new to Orientdb and I am looking to know more about how I can use nodejs with orientdb. Any sites , suggestions , videos will be helpful .. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find some examples in the OrientDB official documentation: https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/OrientJS.html#orientjs-driver

Anyway, this is an example of connection:

```
var OrientDB = require('orientjs');

 var server = OrientDB({

     host: 'localhost',
     port: 2424,
     username: 'root',
     password: 'root'

 });

 var db = server.use({

     name:  'GratefulDeadConcerts',
     username: 'root',
     password: 'root'

 });

 server.close();
```

Hope it helps

Regards